# Reading JSON / array of JSONs from set of files

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a series of files, each with a JSON, that I'd like to read into Pandas. This is pretty straightforward:

```
data_unfiltered = [json.load(open(jf)) for jf in json_input_files]
# next call used to be df = pandas.DataFrame(data_unfiltered)
# instead, json_normalize flattens nested dicts
df = json_normalize(data_unfiltered)
```

Now, a new wrinkle. Some of these input files no longer have just a plain JSON but instead a (python) list of JSONs: `[ { JSON }, { JSON }... ]`.

`json.load` is pretty great because it inputs a whole file and puts it straight into JSON; I don't have to parse the file at all. How would I now turn a list of files, some of which have a single JSON object and some of which have a list of JSON objects, into a list of parsed JSON objects?

Bonus question: I used to be able to add the filename into each JSON with

```
df['filename'] = pandas.Series(json_input_files).values
```

but now I can't do that any more since now one input file might correspond to many JSONs in the output list. How can I add the filenames to the JSONs before I put them into a pandas dataframe?

Edit: Work in progress, per request in comments:

```
data_unfiltered = []
for jf_file in json_input_files:
    jf = open(jf_file)
    if isinstance(jf, list):  # this is obviously wrong
        for j in jf:
            d = json.load(j)   # this is what I need to fix
            d['details'] = jf_file
            data_unfiltered.append(d)
    else:  # not a list, assume dict
        d = json.load(jf)
        d['details'] = jf_file
        data_unfiltered.append(d)
```

but `json.load()` worked perfectly for what I wanted (file object to JSON) and has no equiv for arrays. I figure I have to manually parse the file into a list of blobs and then do `json.loads()` on each blob? That's pretty kludgey though.

Comment: Did you try anything already?

Comment: could you please share an example , your json structure and what is ecpected .... i wuold give you the corresponding code then

Comment: First, in your example code, how is `isinstance(jf, list)` ever going to be true? Then secondly, if you have a list of JSON (whatever that means, I suppose it means a list of dicts in that case) then this is still valid JSON and you can use the very same `json.load` method. Then just use `extend` when you got a list and `append` when you got a dict.

Comment: The example code is wrong. I totally acknowledge that. Responding to @tripleee 's request to see what I'd tried.

Comment: I don't believe `json.load()` inputs an array. It only expects a JSON object (a dict).

Comment: @jowens `json.load` will return whatever JSON value is read from the file, which could be a string, a number, a array, an object, or a null value.

Comment: @chepner: Ohhhhh. OK. So then just do what @a_guest said, read whatever's there, and use isinstance to see if it's a list and then `extend`/`append` accordingly?

Comment: If the input is valid JSON, just read it. If it's not valid JSON, perhaps still clarify how exactly it is not.